# My wordpress ask me to update jquery to use the revolution slider plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

my WP website shows the following message:

The current version of jQuery: 1,6,4
Please update your jQuery to min. 1.7 in case you wish to use the revolution slider plugin.

This is the website: http://www.beegroup-cimne.com/resources/

Anyone can help on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380/comments?page=31

Comment: I've found the problem and solved.

Comment: Thanks for the interest @SanojSharma  I've found the problem and solved. The problem was that in the Revolution slider appears  the message: "The current version of jQuery...in case you wihs to use the revolution slider plugin". This was cause because I've added a Jotform with html code and it cause conflict with the revolution slider.